# Get source code of website loaded in current tab - Chrome extension programming

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm programming a *host proof application* which "by definition" requires to chcek source code on client side (html,js,css).
This is best done (I believe) by extension for browser that takes source code, and generate checksum (e.g. sha1 or md5 which is implemented via javascript)
Is there any way to get source code of currently opened tab ? 
(body.innerHTML or head.innerHTML is not enough)
application is after developement standalone, so all javascript,css is bundled into just one file, therefore checking is easy (no need for parsing and hashing any external scripts, style sheets,...)

Comment: Can you explain why body.innerHTML is not enough?

Comment: because attacker could inject malicious JS code between end head tag and start body tag, which is not valid, but I believe that browsers could render it as regular javascript ...

Answer (score 1):

`body.innerHTML` and `head.innerHTML` should be enough. On this test doc:

```
<script>alert("1");</script>
<html>
    <script>alert("2");</script>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <script>alert("3");</script>
    <body>
        body
    </body>
    <script>alert("4");</script>
</html>
<script>alert("5");</script>
```

it automatically put alerts 1, 2, and 3 into `head.innerHTML`, while alerts 4 and 5 went to `body.innerHTML`.